# Background Image appears on Select Box HTML

Tags: html, css, select

I am customizing the select option box in html and css. I wanted to add a scroll in option box. But after adding a scroll i am facing a problem where the image of checked box remains on screen.

This is the example I'm working with.

```css
.selectbox {
 width: 30%;
}
.selectWrapper {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background:#FFFFFF url('https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/down-chevron-1438184-1216147.png') right 13px center no-repeat;
 
}

.selectWrapper select {
        padding: 12px 40px 12px 20px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 18px;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: none;
        background: transparent;
        background-image: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        outline: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        text-indent: 0.01px;
        text-overflow: scroll;
    }
```

```html
<div class="selectbox">
  <div class="selectWrapper">
  <select id="selectOpt" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
   <option>Lorem</option>
   <option>Parturient</option>
   <option>Euismod</option>
   <option>Lorem</option>
   <option>Parturient</option>
   <option>Euismod</option>
   <option>Lorem</option>
   <option>Parturient</option>
   <option>Euismod</option>
   <option>Lorem</option>
   <option>Parturient</option>
   <option>Euismod</option>
   <option>Lorem</option>
   <option>Parturient</option>
   <option>Euismod</option>
   <option>Lorem</option>
   <option>Parturient</option>
   <option>Euismod</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Could you be more specific what your end result should look like? Does the image need to be hidden after the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add  `background-position: 95% 0;` and `background-size: 40px;` to **selectWrapper**

Here is the updated fiddle:

```css
.selectbox {
  width: 30%;
}

.selectWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #FFFFFF url(https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-256/down-chevron-1438184-1216147.png) right 0 center no-repeat;
  background-position: 95% 0;
  background-size: 40px;
}

.selectWrapper select {
  padding: 12px 40px 12px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 0.01px;
  text-overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="selectbox">
  <div class="selectWrapper">
    <select id="selectOpt" onfocus='this.size=5;' onblur='this.size=1;' onchange='this.size=1; this.blur();'>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Parturient</option>
      <option>Euismod</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Parturient</option>
      <option>Euismod</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Parturient</option>
      <option>Euismod</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Parturient</option>
      <option>Euismod</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Parturient</option>
      <option>Euismod</option>
      <option>Lorem</option>
      <option>Parturient</option>
      <option>Euismod</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```